# Simplest way to create a file and write a string to it in Python

Tags: python, file

Is there any simpler way for writing a string to a file than this:

```
f = open("test.txt", "w+")
f.write("test")
f.close()
```

I wish the return value of write was not None so that I could do this:

```
open("test.txt", "w+").write("test").close()
```

Comment: fewer lines != better code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as f_out:
    f_out.write(your_string)
```

When you use `with open`, you don't need to do `f_out.close()`; this is done for you automatically.

Comment: `with open('test.txt', 'w') as f: f.write('text')`  if you must have a one-liner.  And it's four characters shorter than your desired `open("test.txt", "w+").write("test").close()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do chaining if you want, but you will have to write your own wrapper, useless but fun exercise

```
class MyFile(file):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyFile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def write(self, data):
        super(MyFile, self).write(data)
        return self


MyFile("/tmp/tmp.txt","w").write('xxx').close()
```